# How to set the default directory in Komodo from an an extension?

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I'm working on a KomodoIDE/KomodoEdit extension that creates a new file and then opens it in a new editing tab using

```
...
var obsvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].
getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
...
Display.initWithPath(Target.path);
Display.append(what);

try {
  obsvc.notifyObservers(null, 'open-url', "file://" + Display.path);
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

which works, but I would also like it to set Komodo's default directory to the same directory where this file lives, but I don't see a way to do that automatically.

I found the doCommand...

```
ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_openDirectory')
```

but this just launches a file dialog that asks the user to pick a directory. I'd like to do something to set it programatically using something like...

```
obsvc.notifyObservers(null, 'open-directory', "file://" + Display.path);
```

(which I know doesn't work but is sort of the idea).

Answer (score 0):

The nsIFile interface provides this:

```
// Get current working directory

var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
       getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
       get("CurProcD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
```

The Komodo preferences service would also be an option:

```
    var gprefs = Components.classes["@activestate.com/koPrefService;1"].
      getService(Components.interfaces.koIPrefService).prefs;
    gprefs.setStringPref("mruDirectory", "Display.path);
```

**References**

- [How do I get the path of the project folder](http://community.activestate.com/node/6535)
- [Getting Special Files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Getting_special_files)
- [Komodo JS Macro - insert a relative path from the current editor file](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577306/)
- [mruDirectory](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/src/prefs/prefs.p.xml#L106)
- [XPCOM API Reference](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/xpcom/book/cxc/html/appB.html)
- [Komodo Profile Structure](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-profile-structure)
- [Where does Komodo Store File Preferences](http://community.activestate.com/forum/where-does-komodo-store-file-preferences)
- [Getting/Setting a Komodo Preference](http://community.activestate.com/faq/getting-setting-komodo-preference)

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that the ko.places.manager object has a function to set the default Places window-pane directory. Below is an example of how I used it. The uri should be set to the full directory path and, in the case of Windows, backslashes should get escaped...

```
function SetPlace(ko, uri) {
    try {
    ko.places.manager.openDirURI("file:///" + uri.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\") );
    } catch(e) {
    alert("Could not set place to: " + uri.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\") + "\n" + e);
    }
}
```